# "column IN (X)" vs. "column = X" -- does it affect query performance?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select * from Table_foo where column_bar = 'x'  

select * from Table_foo where column_bar in ('x')
```

Do these two queries perform similarly?

Comment: Your use of double quotes would make Oracle think you're referring to the column x, not a string literal 'x'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Oracle is clever enough to see that there is no difference and will use the same access path.

If in doubt, take a look at the execution plan.

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, they should behave identically.

Also note that you should be using apostrophes and not double quotes.

Comment: True. Double quotes is for names of schema objects, not for String literals.